# Use jQuery replaceWith(); on specific class

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, append, replacewith

I have a table of contacts that is populated via PHP/MySQL. Each contact is in its own line, and its class name is "line," plus the row number, e.g. "line01" or "line02."

I have a jQuery modal dialog that I'm using to add new contacts, edit current contacts, and delete contacts. I am using `.replaceWith()` for editing and `.append();` for adding new contacts.  My challenge now is to get the edit function working correctly so that it only replaces the `<div>` row that is being edited, and not all of the rows.

How do I select the particular element to replace, or make sure that the row being replaced has the same ID of the row that is being edited? Should be simple enough, but I just haven't been able to get it working correctly. Help is appreciated!

Here is the code I have so far:

```
$("#contact-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
            "Add Contact": function() {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                bValid = bValid && checkLength( contact_first_name, "first name", 2, 64 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( contact_last_name, "last name", 2, 64 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( title, "title", 1, 64 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( phone, "phone", 6, 30 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( email_address, "email_address", 5, 128 );       

                /* Handle edit function */                  
                if (crow.val().length > 0) {
                    if ( bValid ) {
                        if (contact_count % 2) {
                          //$( "#contacts" ).html(
                         // '<div class="line'+contact_count+'">' +
                         $('.line'+contact_count).replaceWith(
                            '<div class="action gray">' +
                            '<a href="javascript:edit_contact('+contact_count+');"><img src="images/icons/edit.png" width="15" height="16" border="0" /></a>' +
                            '<a href="javascript:delete_contact('+contact_count+');"><img src="images/icons/trash.png" width="11" height="16" border="0" /></a>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="contact gray"><input type="hidden" id="contact-first-name'+contact_count+'" name="contact_first_name[]" value="'+contact_first_name.val()+'" />' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="contact-last-name'+contact_count+'" name="contact_last_name[]" value="'+contact_last_name.val()+'" />'+contact_first_name.val()+' '+contact_last_name.val()+'</div>' +
                            '<div class="phone gray"><input type="hidden" id="cphone'+contact_count+'" name="cphone[]" value="'+phone.val()+'" />'+phone.val()+'</div>' +
                            '<div class="email gray"><input type="hidden" id="email-address'+contact_count+'" name="email_address[]" value="'+email_address.val()+'" />'+email_address.val()+'</div>' +
                            '<div class="primary gray"><input type="radio" id="primary'+contact_count+'" name="primary[]" value="1" /></div>' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="twitter'+contact_count+'" name="twitter[]" value="'+twitter.val()+'" />' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="facebook'+contact_count+'" name="facebook[]" value="'+facebook.val()+'" />' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="linkedin'+contact_count+'" name="linkedin[]" value="'+linkedin.val()+'" />' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="title'+contact_count+'" name="title[]" value="'+title.val()+'" />' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="clear"></div>');
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                          } 
                       else {
                          //$( "#contacts" ).html( 
                           // '<div class="line'+contact_count+'">' +
                          $('.line'+contact_count).replaceWith(
                            '<div class="action">' +
                            '<a href="javascript:edit_contact('+contact_count+');"><img src="images/icons/edit.png" width="15" height="16" border="0" /></a>' +
                            '<a href="javascript:delete_contact('+contact_count+');"><img src="images/icons/trash.png" width="11" height="16" border="0" /></a>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="contact"><input type="hidden" id="contact-first-name'+contact_count+'" name="contact_first_name[]" value="'+contact_first_name.val()+'" />' + 
                            '<input type="hidden" id="contact-last-name'+contact_count+'" name="contact_last_name[]" value="'+contact_last_name.val()+'" />'+contact_first_name.val()+' '+contact_last_name.val()+'</div>' +
                            '<div class="phone"><input type="hidden" id="cphone'+contact_count+'" name="cphone[]" value="'+phone.val()+'" />'+phone.val()+'</div>' +
                            '<div class="email"><input type="hidden" id="email-address'+contact_count+'" name="email_address[]" value="'+email_address.val()+'" />'+email_address.val()+'</div>' +
                            '<div class="primary"><input type="radio" id="primary'+contact_count+'" name="primary[]" value="1" /></div>' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="twitter'+contact_count+'" name="twitter[]" value="'+twitter.val()+'" />' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="facebook'+contact_count+'" name="facebook[]" value="'+facebook.val()+'" />' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="linkedin'+contact_count+'" name="linkedin[]" value="'+linkedin.val()+'" />' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="title'+contact_count+'" name="title[]" value="'+title.val()+'" />' +
                            '</div><div class="clear"></div>');
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                        contact_count++;
                     }

                }
                /* Handle new contact rows */
                else if ( bValid ) {
                    if (contact_count % 2) {
                      $( "#contacts" ).append(
                        '<div class="line'+contact_count+'">' +
                        '<div class="action gray">' +
                        '<a href="javascript:edit_contact('+contact_count+');"><img src="images/icons/edit.png" width="15" height="16" border="0" /></a>' +
                        '<a href="javascript:delete_contact('+contact_count+');"><img src="images/icons/trash.png" width="11" height="16" border="0" /></a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="contact gray"><input type="hidden" id="contact-first-name'+contact_count+'" name="contact_first_name[]" value="'+contact_first_name.val()+'" />' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="contact-last-name'+contact_count+'" name="contact_last_name[]" value="'+contact_last_name.val()+'" />'+contact_first_name.val()+' '+contact_last_name.val()+'</div>' +
                        '<div class="phone gray"><input type="hidden" id="cphone'+contact_count+'" name="cphone[]" value="'+phone.val()+'" />'+phone.val()+'</div>' +
                        '<div class="email gray"><input type="hidden" id="email-address'+contact_count+'" name="email_address[]" value="'+email_address.val()+'" />'+email_address.val()+'</div>' +
                        '<div class="primary gray"><input type="radio" id="primary'+contact_count+'" name="primary[]" value="1" /></div>' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="twitter'+contact_count+'" name="twitter[]" value="'+twitter.val()+'" />' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="facebook'+contact_count+'" name="facebook[]" value="'+facebook.val()+'" />' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="linkedin'+contact_count+'" name="linkedin[]" value="'+linkedin.val()+'" />' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="title'+contact_count+'" name="title[]" value="'+title.val()+'" />' +
                        '</div><div class="clear"></div>');
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                      } else {
                      $( "#contacts" ).append( 
                        '<div class="line'+contact_count+'">' +
                        '<div class="action">' +
                        '<a href="javascript:edit_contact('+contact_count+');"><img src="images/icons/edit.png" width="15" height="16" border="0" /></a>' +
                        '<a href="javascript:delete_contact('+contact_count+');"><img src="images/icons/trash.png" width="11" height="16" border="0" /></a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="contact"><input type="hidden" id="contact-first-name'+contact_count+'" name="contact_first_name[]" value="'+contact_first_name.val()+'" />' + 
                        '<input type="hidden" id="contact-last-name'+contact_count+'" name="contact_last_name[]" value="'+contact_last_name.val()+'" />'+contact_first_name.val()+' '+contact_last_name.val()+'</div>' +
                        '<div class="phone"><input type="hidden" id="cphone'+contact_count+'" name="cphone[]" value="'+phone.val()+'" />'+phone.val()+'</div>' +
                        '<div class="email"><input type="hidden" id="email-address'+contact_count+'" name="email_address[]" value="'+email_address.val()+'" />'+email_address.val()+'</div>' +
                        '<div class="primary"><input type="radio" id="primary'+contact_count+'" name="primary[]" value="1" /></div>' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="twitter'+contact_count+'" name="twitter[]" value="'+twitter.val()+'" />' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="facebook'+contact_count+'" name="facebook[]" value="'+facebook.val()+'" />' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="linkedin'+contact_count+'" name="linkedin[]" value="'+linkedin.val()+'" />' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="title'+contact_count+'" name="title[]" value="'+title.val()+'" />' +
                        '</div><div class="clear"></div>');
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                      }
                      contact_count++;                      
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });
```

**Edit:** Here is the code for `edit_contact()`:

```
function edit_contact(contact_line, cid) {
    // $('#contact-dialog-link').val('edit');
    $('#contact-dialog-id').val(cid);
    $('#contact-first-name').val($('.line'+contact_line+' #contact-first-name'+contact_line).val());
    $('#contact-last-name').val($('.line'+contact_line+' #contact-last-name'+contact_line).val());
    $('#title').val($('.line'+contact_line+' #title'+contact_line).val());
    $('#cphone').val($('.line'+contact_line+' #cphone'+contact_line).val());
    $('#email-address').val($('.line'+contact_line+' #email-address'+contact_line).val());
    $('#twitter').val($('.line'+contact_line+' #twitter'+contact_line).val());
    $('#facebook').val($('.line'+contact_line+' #facebook'+contact_line).val());
    $('#linkedin').val($('.line'+contact_line+' #linkedin'+contact_line).val());
    $('#contact-update').val(contact_line);
    $('#contact-dialog-link').trigger('click');
}
```

**Edit:** Here is the PHP that handles the save function:

```
if ($_POST && $_POST['type'] == 'add-to-contacts') {
$fid = $_SESSION['facility_current'];
if ($_POST['input'] == 'edit') {
//  if ($_POST['contact-update'] == ''){
    $dbQuery = sprintf("UPDATE facility_contacts SET fid=%d, first_name='%s', last_name='%s', title='%s', phone='%s', email_address='%s', twitter='%s', facebook='%s', linkedin='%s' WHERE cid = %d;", $fid,$_POST['first_name'],$_POST['last_name'],$_POST['title'],$_POST['phone'],$_POST['email_address'],$_POST['twitter'],$_POST['facebook'],$_POST['linkedin'],$_POST['cid']);
} else {
    $dbQuery = sprintf("INSERT INTO facility_contacts (fid, first_name, last_name, title, phone, email_address, twitter, facebook, linkedin) VALUES (%d,'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');", $fid,$_POST['first_name'],$_POST['last_name'],$_POST['title'],$_POST['phone'],$_POST['email_address'],$_POST['twitter'],$_POST['facebook'],$_POST['linkedin']);
}
$dbResult = $dbc->query($dbQuery,__FILE__,__LINE__);
unapprove_proof_status();
echo ($dbResult) ? true : false;
exit;
```

}

Comment: where is the code for `edit_contact('+contact_count+');` ?

Comment: also if you did something like - `var alt = contact_count % 2 ? ' gray', '';` then you could get rid of a lot of repeating code for your alternating line style

Comment: Thanks, Kavun. I added the code for edit_contact(). Where would I do the var for the gray class attribute? I would love to simplify that structure.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if your selectors for `$('#contact-first-name').val()` are specific enough. You may need something like `$('#contact-first-name', '.line'+contact_line).val()` to select the contact `input` item within a specific `<div class="line'+contact_count+'">`. I would try this:

```
$("#contact-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 600,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
            "Add Contact": function() {
                var bValid = true;
                allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

                bValid = bValid && checkLength( contact_first_name, "first name", 2, 64 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( contact_last_name, "last name", 2, 64 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( title, "title", 1, 64 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( phone, "phone", 6, 30 );
                bValid = bValid && checkLength( email_address, "email_address", 5, 128 );       

                var alt = contact_count % 2 ? ' gray': '';

                /* Handle edit function */                  
                if (crow.val().length > 0) {
                    if ( bValid ) {
                         $('.line'+contact_count).replaceWith(
                            '<div class="action' + alt + '">' +
                            '<a href="javascript:edit_contact('+contact_count+');"><img src="images/icons/edit.png" width="15" height="16" border="0" /></a>' +
                            '<a href="javascript:delete_contact('+contact_count+');"><img src="images/icons/trash.png" width="11" height="16" border="0" /></a>' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="contact' + alt + '"><input type="hidden" id="contact-first-name'+contact_count+'" name="contact_first_name[]" value="'+contact_first_name.val()+'" />' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="contact-last-name'+contact_count+'" name="contact_last_name[]" value="'+contact_last_name.val()+'" />'+contact_first_name.val()+' '+contact_last_name.val()+'</div>' +
                            '<div class="phone' + alt + '"><input type="hidden" id="cphone'+contact_count+'" name="cphone[]" value="'+phone.val()+'" />'+phone.val()+'</div>' +
                            '<div class="email' + alt + '"><input type="hidden" id="email-address'+contact_count+'" name="email_address[]" value="'+email_address.val()+'" />'+email_address.val()+'</div>' +
                            '<div class="primary' + alt + '"><input type="radio" id="primary'+contact_count+'" name="primary[]" value="1" /></div>' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="twitter'+contact_count+'" name="twitter[]" value="'+twitter.val()+'" />' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="facebook'+contact_count+'" name="facebook[]" value="'+facebook.val()+'" />' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="linkedin'+contact_count+'" name="linkedin[]" value="'+linkedin.val()+'" />' +
                            '<input type="hidden" id="title'+contact_count+'" name="title[]" value="'+title.val()+'" />' +
                            '</div>' +
                            '<div class="clear"></div>');
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                        contact_count++;
                     }

                }
                /* Handle new contact rows */
                else if ( bValid ) {
                      $( "#contacts" ).append(
                        '<div class="line'+contact_count+'">' +
                        '<div class="action' + alt + '">' +
                        '<a href="javascript:edit_contact('+contact_count+');"><img src="images/icons/edit.png" width="15" height="16" border="0" /></a>' +
                        '<a href="javascript:delete_contact('+contact_count+');"><img src="images/icons/trash.png" width="11" height="16" border="0" /></a>' +
                        '</div>' +
                        '<div class="contact' + alt + '"><input type="hidden" id="contact-first-name'+contact_count+'" name="contact_first_name[]" value="'+contact_first_name.val()+'" />' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="contact-last-name'+contact_count+'" name="contact_last_name[]" value="'+contact_last_name.val()+'" />'+contact_first_name.val()+' '+contact_last_name.val()+'</div>' +
                        '<div class="phone' + alt + '"><input type="hidden" id="cphone'+contact_count+'" name="cphone[]" value="'+phone.val()+'" />'+phone.val()+'</div>' +
                        '<div class="email' + alt + '"><input type="hidden" id="email-address'+contact_count+'" name="email_address[]" value="'+email_address.val()+'" />'+email_address.val()+'</div>' +
                        '<div class="primary' + alt + '"><input type="radio" id="primary'+contact_count+'" name="primary[]" value="1" /></div>' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="twitter'+contact_count+'" name="twitter[]" value="'+twitter.val()+'" />' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="facebook'+contact_count+'" name="facebook[]" value="'+facebook.val()+'" />' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="linkedin'+contact_count+'" name="linkedin[]" value="'+linkedin.val()+'" />' +
                        '<input type="hidden" id="title'+contact_count+'" name="title[]" value="'+title.val()+'" />' +
                        '</div><div class="clear"></div>');
                        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                      contact_count++;                      
                }
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            }
        },
        close: function() {
            allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        }
    });

function edit_contact(contact_line, cid) {
    $('#contact-dialog-id').val(cid);
    $('#contact-first-name', '.line'+contact_line).val($('.line'+contact_line+' #contact-first-name'+contact_line).val());
    $('#contact-last-name', '.line'+contact_line).val($('.line'+contact_line+' #contact-last-name'+contact_line).val());
    $('#title', '.line'+contact_line).val($('.line'+contact_line+' #title'+contact_line).val());
    $('#cphone', '.line'+contact_line).val($('.line'+contact_line+' #cphone'+contact_line).val());
    $('#email-address', '.line'+contact_line).val($('.line'+contact_line+' #email-address'+contact_line).val());
    $('#twitter', '.line'+contact_line).val($('.line'+contact_line+' #twitter'+contact_line).val());
    $('#facebook', '.line'+contact_line).val($('.line'+contact_line+' #facebook'+contact_line).val());
    $('#linkedin', '.line'+contact_line).val($('.line'+contact_line+' #linkedin'+contact_line).val());
    $('#contact-update').val(contact_line);
    $('#contact-dialog-link').trigger('click');
}
```

By using `$('#itemToUpdate', '#divWhereItLives')`, you can set a context for where to find the item to update - see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

**Edit:** should have been `var alt = contact_count % 2 ? ' gray': '';`. Sorry

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. I am trying this, but I'm getting a Console error on this line: 

`var alt = contact_count % 2 ? ' gray', '';`

The error is a Syntax Error: Unexpected string

Comment: When I first tried this code, the form did not pre-populate with the existing data when I clicked the dit button as it used to do. I switched back to the old `edit_contact()` function, and the pre-populating worked. When I edit data, it still does not save. I think that's the part that I need to troubleshoot.

Comment: maybe there is a click handler on `$('#contact-dialog-link').trigger('click');` that processes the edit?

Comment: whatever handles the save button click on your edit dialog is what you should look at

Comment: I don't think there is a click handler on `$('#contact-dialog-link').trigger('click');`. The `replaceWith()` is intended to replace the data in the form (rather than append it), and then the PHP function actually saves it to the database, along with a ton of other info. So the catch is still getting `replaceWith()` to work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17775/discussion-between-kavun-and-deewilcox)